# How to evaluate Environment Variables (SERVER_PORT in particular) in Apache Config

Tags: apache-2.4

An Apache-2.4 server listens on two ports 80 and 81.

What is the simplest way to set an environment variable based on which port a request came in? In particular, I want to set HTTPS=on if port 81 is used.

Neither of the following worked:

```
SetEnvIf SERVER_PORT 81 HTTPS=on
SetEnvIf %{SERVER_PORT} 81 HTTPS=on
```

The [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html) specify that environment variables can be used but only if they are associated with the request (for example set with SetEnv). SERVER_PORT doesn't seem to be working. Or maybe I did not use the correct syntax.

Finally, with lot's of googling, I found out that mod_rewrite can be used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 81
RewriteRule ".*" "-" [E=HTTPS:on]
```

It seems a bit overkill to use mod_rewrite however. Is there a simpler solution?

**Edit:** Why do I need this:

Our Apache is behind a firewall which terminates HTTPS. All HTTP-traffic is forwarded to Apache's port 80. And HTTPS-traffic is forwarded as plain HTTP to port 81. The firewall is not able to add any custom HTTP headers (like X-Forwarded-Proto). So the only way to determine if HTTPS was used is by detecting on which port the connection came in.

Comment: Is it possible to create two virtual hosts (one for each port) and just use basic `SetEnv` inside the port 81 vhost?

Comment: Yes I tried it. And it's actually not a bad solution. I moved most of the config into a separate file which I included in each VirtualHost, in order to avoid duplicating the common config. I am still a bit surprised though that SetEnvIf doesn't work.